# Can we use "much more superior"?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

> My game is much more superior to yours.

Can we use much more in this sentence?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't say: *My game is ***much more** superior to yours.*
But say: *My game is **far** superior to yours.*

This is because *superior* is a non-gradable adjective. Non-gradable adjectives can't be used comparatively or superlatively. (In other words, you can't say or write ***more superior*** or ***most superior*** in comparison sentences.)

---

Most grammar books would cover gradable and non-gradable adjectives. [The British Council also has a page for it.](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/adjectives-gradable-non-gradable)

Some dictionaries also let the reader know whether an adjective is gradable or non-gradable. For example, the [Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=pqlRO2jdI2gC&pg=PA958) makes it clear that *superior* is [not gradable], as shown in the image below:

[image: Extract from Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary]

Comment: And if it was gradable, then it would only make sense as "my game is more superior to yours than his is".

Comment: "Much superior" is OK, as is "much better / worse / hotter / colder", etc. "Much more + adjective" is sometimes OK, e.g. "Much more hot / cold", but "much more good" or "much more bad" sound wrong compared with "much better" and "much worse". The meaning of "superior" is comparative in itself, and there don't seem to be English words "????", "superior", "????" corresponding to comparatives like "hot" "hotter", "hottest" and "good", "better", "best".

Comment: "Much more hot" is not correct in my AmE dialect, only "much hotter". "More hot" is "hotter". "More good" is "better". We only use "more adjective" when we are forming a comparative, like "more appropriate", or "more famous". We don't use more (in standard English) with something that is already in a comparative form, like "more better", or has a single word comparative form, like "greener" instead of "more green".  @alephzero